# Converting casing in MS word

Tags: vba, ms-word, uppercase

The code below converts words in a specific style into title case, except for acronyms.

However, there are specific words that I would like to add for the exception and these words should stay in lower case format (and, for, but, etc.)

So far, this is what I came up with:

```
Public Sub TitleCaseDocument()
   Dim myDoc As Document: Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
   Dim myPara As Word.Paragraph

   For Each myPara In myDoc.StoryRanges.Item(wdMainTextStory).Paragraphs

       If myPara.Style.NameLocal = "K Level 1" Then
           TitleParagraph myPara
      End If

   Next
End Sub

Public Sub TitleParagraph(ByVal ipPara As Word.Paragraph)

   Dim myText As Range

   For Each myText In ipPara.Range.Words

       If Not UCase$(myText.Text) = myText.Text Then
           myText.Words.Item(1).Case = wdTitleWord
       End If
   Next
 End Sub
```

Update 2020-May-12 Revised code below trying to add an array but still not working

```
 Public Sub TitleCaseDocument()
   Dim myDoc As Document: Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
   Dim myPara As Word.Paragraph

   For Each myPara In myDoc.StoryRanges.Item(wdMainTextStory).Paragraphs

       If myPara.Style.NameLocal = "K Level 1" Then
           TitleParagraph myPara
      End If

   Next
End Sub

Public Sub TitleParagraph(ByVal ipPara As Word.Paragraph)

   Dim myText As Range
   Dim Strtext As String
   Strtext = "and,of"
   For Each myText In ipPara.Range.Words

       If Not UCase$(myText.Text) = myText.Text Then
           myText.Words.Item(1).Case = wdTitleWord

       Else If Not Strtext = myText.Text Then
           myText.Words.Item(1).Case = wdTitleWord

       End If
   Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: So make an array of the words that should not be changed and loop that array for each word to see if it matches.

Comment: See:  https://www.msofficeforums.com/78192-post3.html

Comment: Tried incorporating an array above but not sure if I'm doing it wrong as it is still converting words in the array into uppercase